# Animating an image with FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-animation

So, I'm trying to animate some pixels moving around a static image using FuncAnimation. The static image itself is 256x256 and the objects moving around are essentially a brightly colored pixel. In the end i'd like for the animation to go indefinitely or until I stop it but thats besides the point. Right now I'd like to get things moving first.

The static image in question is this one (for this example anyways).

[image]

The code below is a simple class consisting of a location and color. When i spawn it or move it i make sure to record the previous pixel color so the object doesnt leave 'tracks' sort of speak.

```
class Prey:
    def __init__(self, color = [255, 0, 255]) -> None:
        self.color  = color
    
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def set_spawn(self, world):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 256)
        self.y = random.randint(0, 256)

        while np.array_equal(world[self.x][self.y], [65, 105, 225]):
            self.x = random.randint(0, 256)
            self.y = random.randint(0, 256)
        
        prev_pix = world[self.x, self.y]
        return prev_pix

    def move(self, world, x, y):
        if not np.array_equal(world[x][y], [65,  105, 225]):
            prev_pix = ((self.x, self.y), world[x][y])
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        return prev_pix
```

And below here I actually try to animate the damn thing.

```
def load_map(wname):
    bgr_world = cv2.imread(wname)
    rgb_world = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_world, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return rgb_world

world = load_map('m3.png')
fig = plt.figure('lifesim')
im = plt.imshow(world, animated=True)
p1 = Prey()

def movement(*args):
    x1, y1, prev_pix1 = p1.move(world, p1.x+1, p1.y) #i'm trying to get it to move down (when it actually works ill make sure it doesnt go OOB)
    ppxy, pp = prev_pix1
    ppx, ppy = ppxy
    world[ppx][ppy] = pp

    world[x1][y1] = p1.color
    im.set_array(world)
    return world,

def init_game(world):
    x0, y0, prev_pix0 = p1.set_spawn(world) #The spawn is random, so i just overwrote it here so i can test
    prev_pix0 = world[110, 100]
    x0, y0 = (110, 100)
    p1.x = 110
    p1.y = 100

    world[x0][y0] = p1.color

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, movement, blit=True)
    plt.show()

def main():
     init_game(world)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And when the code gets eventually executed, i get the following error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 241, in resize
    self.resize_event()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1767, in resize_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 229, in process
    self.exception_handler(exc)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 81, in _exception_printer
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1275, in _on_resize
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1719, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1747, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = sorted(self._drawn_artists,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1748, in <lambda>
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_zorder'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 253, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 407, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1870, in draw
    self.canvas.draw_event(renderer)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1759, in draw_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 229, in process
    self.exception_handler(exc)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 81, in _exception_printer
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 975, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1719, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1747, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = sorted(self._drawn_artists,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1748, in <lambda>
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_zorder'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here since I'm completely new to matplotlibs animation modules... The mistake is probably blisteringly obvious but I just can't see it.

Comment: Your error message is clear. You are supposing somewhere that a 'numpy.ndarray' has an attribute 'get_zorder', which is not true.

Do a pattern matching for 'get_zorder' in your codebase to see where the problem is happening.

Comment: I dont explicitly call for that attribute though, according to the traceback, it happens in matplotlibs backend. Specifically here `File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1748, in <lambda>
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())`. I'm not sure how to bypass this. Sorry I couldn't respond earlier SO was still down for me.

Comment: Then the issue might be that you are giving a numpy.ndarray where you shouldn't. Do you have the complete traceback of the error ?

Comment: @python123 i will edit the question and paste the complete traceback

Comment: Should the function `movement` really return a tuple ?  I mean, is the line `return world,`, correct ?

Comment: the `movement` function returns an array, the `move` function returns a tuple with new coordinates and coordinates of the previous pixel so i can reset its color after the object moves.

Comment: Could you put all the info to reproduce the problem ? The requirements.txt and all the imports

Comment: `import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation`

these are the requirements to get the thing going

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242892/discussion-between-loogie-and-python123).